# Jqgrid virtual scrolling load next set of rows programmatically

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-php, jqgrid-formatter, mvcjqgrid

I am using Jqgrid with virtual scrolling, I am loading the first 25 records in the grid. I would like based on certain action to load the next 25 records when I click on a button instead of scrolling down with the scrollbar.

Is there any way of reloading the grid with the next 25 records?